# copy-flex-resources not working in flexmojos

Tags: apache-flex, maven, build

I am trying to copy the dependent into war using the copy- flex-resources plugin. However I'm getting the following error :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.2-beta:copy-flex-resources (default) on project myproject: Execution default of goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.2-beta:copy-flex-resources failed. NullPointerException

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId> 
   <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>4.2-beta</version> 
</plugin>
```

I'm all over this issue, but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, but NullPointerException does not say much, try to run maven with parameters -e or -X (or both) to see more logging information to find out what is going on. Also you may try a release version of the plugin, not beta just to be sure. 
And if you also provide part of the pom.xml with your plugin configuration, someone could notice some mistake :).